# save mysql ouput as text?

Tags: 13.04, mysql

I am using Ubuntu 13.04 and installed MySQL Server version: 5.5 .

All I want simply , if I doing a MySQL query then its output should have to store in a text file. How can I achieve this ?

for example :

```
select * from raja
```

then output of table raja should have to store in a text file along with terminal display.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
mysql -u username -p -e 'select * from raja;' database_name >> file_name.txt
```

If you want to append use `>>` otherwise `>`.

Answer (score 1):

mysql -u**user** -p**passowrd** -e 'SQL Query' database > filetosave

```
-u : Specify mysql database user name
-p : Prompt for password
-e : Execute sql query
database : Specify database name
```

So for your case:

```
    mysql -u raja -p -e 'select * from raja' rajadb > results
```

Comment: He posted before you did , and Its worked. So I am accepting his answer. Both are great answers.Thank you.:)